# Unable to import python dependencies that come with miniconda in a Docker run

Tags: python, docker, miniconda

I am trying to run a python script inside a dockerized miniconda environment. The issue I am facing is that when I `docker run` interactively(-it) and run the script manually inside, it works great. But when I `docker run` non-interactively, the modules that come with miniconda installation like `cryptography`, `lxml`, are not found.

My dockerfile:

```
ARG REGISTRY=harbor-west.reg.com/ci
ARG FROM_TAG=master

FROM harbor-west.reg.com/base-os/ubuntu:20.04
USER root

ENV CONDA_DIR $HOME/miniconda3

RUN apt update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        wget
RUN pip install --upgrade \
                    google-api-python-client \
                    grpcio \
                    matplotlib \
                    numpy \
                    opencv-python \
                    pandas \
                    scikit-learn

RUN mkdir /abc
#Download a conda package under /abc/bin - steps removed for simplicity

#install miniconda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN chmod 755 Miniconda3-py38_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN /bin/bash -c "./Miniconda3-py38_23.3.1-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b"
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
RUN /root/miniconda3/condabin/conda init

WORKDIR /abc/bin

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/abc/bin/start-prediction.sh"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["/abc/bin/start-prediction.sh"]
```

Output with non-interactive docker run(unexpected):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prediction_server.py", line 2, in <module>
    from abc.learn import prepare_data, SuperResolution
  File "/abc/bin/abc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from abc.auth.tools import LazyLoader
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import RegSession
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/api.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ._auth import (
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/_auth/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._pki import PKIAuth
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/_auth/_pki.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..tools._lazy import LazyLoader
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .certificate import pfx_to_pem
  File "/abc/bin/abc/auth/tools/certificate.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cryptography
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

Output with interactive docker run(as expected):

```
(base)root@dcc788e0a8c5:/abc/bin# ./start-prediction.sh 
server listening on  0.0.0.0:50443
```

I tried echoing the PATH inside the container and looks ok:

```
/root/miniconda3/bin:/root/miniconda3/condabin:/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I'm not able to figure out what I'm missing. I would think if it works interactively, it should work non-interactively as well. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: `PATH` has nothing to do with locating python packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue.

The key is when you perform `conda init`, it adds some lines in your shell rc, in your case `.bashrc`. [source](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/commands/init.html).

Thus the solution is straightforward: source your `.bashrc`.

Although, you have another solution that does not involve to edit your rc file. You can change your `SHELL` to be in your conda environment. When you are unsing this shell, install the packages requirements and run your code.

```
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "base", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Using the above answer, I just changed my ENTRYPOINT to `["/root/miniconda3/condabin/conda", "run", "-n", "base", "/bin/bash", "-c", "/abc/bin/start-prediction.py"] ` and it worked. I didnt have to edit ~/.bashrc or use SHELL command.